# Disable user field on profile edit page

Tags: 6, forms

I've got a logintoboggan (http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan/) module and my login is an email adress, so I dont want to have a "Name: " field on my profile edit page.

But when i just call in my theme preprocess page:

```
$vars['form']['account']['name']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

or unset() the field I've got an error:

> Username field is required.

How can I disable validation of this field? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username field is a required field in the `{users}` table so it has to be there one way or another.

A way round it might be to remove the "Change own username" permission for authenticated users at http://mysite.com/admin/user/permissions. I can't remember if the field will still display on the user edit form but either way it won't be editable.